# Magento 2: Data Migration From Non Magento Database to Magento Database

Tags: magento2, database, import, custom, migration

I already have One MySQL database which is not in Magento. I need to Map field 1 by 1 & put into Magento 2 Database.

Need to perform Data Migration from Non Magento DB to Magento 2.

There may be some extra fields attributes will be added for Product & Customer & same way some of them will be removed.

Don't think can use Magento 2 Default Admin Import.

I have below options

1. Export Non Magento Database in CSV & Convert it to that CSV in
   Magento CSV format
2. Make a script which fetches data from Non
   Magento Database & Put Entry in relevant Magento 2 Database Tables.

Major part is Images. Following http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import-product-images.html

Customer will provide Zip folder of all images via FTP. They will provide in Product Id/SKU wise format. Need to manage that as well.

Please let me know which is the best method & how to proceed

[Magento 2: Product Import Error - Product Type is invalid or not supported. Duplicates found in column names [SOLVED]](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139587/magento-2-product-import-product-type-is-invalid-error)

Answer (score 1):

You have to just export non magento database in csv format and convert your csv to magento related format to fast import in magento.

You have to manage your csv related to magento specific, saves your time and energy.

For Magento specific product and customer csv, You just need to export csv for each product and customer from

> System -> Data Transfer -> Export

To check magento specific csv.

If you want to create custom script for each customer and product import you need to give more time and energy to workout.

```
If possible make csv file and use default magento admin import functionality.
```

Comment: Magento Default Import has issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6939