# Magento 2: Product Import Error - Product Type is invalid or not supported. Duplicates found in column names [SOLVED]

Tags: magento2, product, import, csv, exception

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.2

**I have exported Sample CSV File from Magento Admin & importing the same file again. Then also it's not working for more than 1 record.
If you have only 1 record, then it works fine.**

Using `attribute_set_code` as `Default`

We have `product_type` column.

I'm using in CSV

```
product_type
simple
```

I'm only checking with more than >1 Product.

```
Data validation failed. Please fix the following errors and upload the file again.
Following Error(s) has been occurred during importing process:
Only the first 100 errors are shown. Download full report
1. Value for 'product_type' attribute contains incorrect value, see acceptable values on settings specified for Admin in row(s): 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101
Checked rows: 101, checked entities: 101, invalid rows: 100, total errors: 100
```

In Downloaded Report in CSV, it's saying

> Value for 'product_type' attribute contains incorrect value, see
>   acceptable values on settings specified for Admin

CSV File data

> sku   store_view_code attribute_set_code  product_type    categories  product_websites    name    description short_description   weight  product_online  tax_class_name  visibility  price   special_price   special_price_from_date special_price_to_date   url_key meta_title  meta_keywords   meta_description    base_image  base_image_label    small_image small_image_label   thumbnail_image thumbnail_image_label   swatch_image    swatch_image_label  created_at  updated_at  new_from_date   new_to_date display_product_options_in  map_price   msrp_price  map_enabled gift_message_available  custom_design   custom_design_from  custom_design_to    custom_layout_update    page_layout product_options_container   msrp_display_actual_price_type  country_of_manufacture  additional_attributes   qty out_of_stock_qty    use_config_min_qty  is_qty_decimal  allow_backorders    use_config_backorders   min_cart_qty    use_config_min_sale_qty max_cart_qty    use_config_max_sale_qty is_in_stock notify_on_stock_below   use_config_notify_stock_qty manage_stock    use_config_manage_stock use_config_qty_increments   qty_increments  use_config_enable_qty_inc   enable_qty_increments   is_decimal_divided  website_id  related_skus    related_position    crosssell_skus  crosssell_position  upsell_skus upsell_position additional_images   additional_image_labels hide_from_product_page  bundle_price_type   bundle_sku_type bundle_price_view   bundle_weight_type  bundle_values   bundle_shipment_type    configurable_variations configurable_variation_labels   associated_skus
>   G232      Default simple  Default Category/Coins  base    Orchid Minted Stamps
>   3-in-1 Silver Set Orchid Minted Stamps 3-in-1 Silver Set  Orchid Minted
>   Stamps 3-in-1 Silver Set  1   1       Catalog,
>   Search    10              orchid-minted-stamps-3-in-1-silver-set  Orchid Minted
>   Stamps 3-in-1 Silver Set  Orchid Minted Stamps 3-in-1 Silver Set  Orchid
>   Minted Stamps 3-in-1 Silver
>   Set   G232-1.png      G232-1.png      G232-1.png      G232-1.png                                                                              100 0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1                           G232-1.png  Image

Sometime it also gives

> Duplicates found in column names: array ( 0 => 'sku', 1 =>
>   'store_view_code', 2 => 'attribute_set_code', 3 => 'product_type', 4
>   => 'categories', 5 => 'product_websites', 6 => 'name', 7 => 'description', 8 => 'short_description', 9 => 'weight', 10 =>
>   'product_online', 11 => 'tax_class_name', 12 => 'visibility', 13 =>
>   'price', 14 => 'special_price', 15 => 'special_price_from_date', 16 =>
>   'special_price_to_date', 17 => 'url_key', 18 => 'meta_title', 19 =>
>   'meta_keywords', 20 => 'meta_description', 21 => 'base_image', 22 =>
>   'base_image_label', 23 => 'small_image', 24 => 'small_image_label', 25
>   => 'thumbnail_image', 26 => 'thumbnail_image_label', 27 => 'swatch_image', 28 => 'swatch_image_label', 29 => 'created_at', 30 =>
>   'updated_at', 31 => 'new_from_date', 32 => 'new_to_date', 33 =>
>   'display_product_options_in', 34 => 'map_price', 35 => 'msrp_price',
>   36 => 'map_enabled', 37 => 'gift_message_available', 38 =>
>   'custom_design', 39 => 'custom_design_from', 40 => 'custom_design_to',
>   41 => 'custom_layout_update', 42 => 'page_layout', 43 =>
>   'product_options_container', 44 => 'msrp_display_actual_price_type',
>   45 => 'country_of_manufacture', 46 => 'additional_attributes', 47 =>
>   'qty', 48 => 'out_of_stock_qty', 49 => 'use_config_min_qty', 50 =>
>   'is_qty_decimal', 51 => 'allow_backorders', 52 =>
>   'use_config_backorders', 53 => 'min_cart_qty', 54 =>
>   'use_config_min_sale_qty', 55 => 'max_cart_qty', 56 =>
>   'use_config_max_sale_qty', 57 => 'is_in_stock', 58 =>
>   'notify_on_stock_below', 59 => 'use_config_notify_stock_qty', 60 =>
>   'manage_stock', 61 => 'use_config_manage_stock', 62 =>
>   'use_config_qty_increments', 63 => 'qty_increments', 64 =>
>   'use_config_enable_qty_inc', 65 => 'enable_qty_increments', 66 =>
>   'is_decimal_divided', 67 => 'website_id', 68 => 'related_skus', 69 =>
>   'related_position', 70 => 'crosssell_skus', 71 =>
>   'crosssell_position', 72 => 'upsell_skus', 73 => 'upsell_position', 74
>   => 'additional_images', 75 => 'additional_image_labels', 76 => 'hide_from_product_page', 77 => 'bundle_price_type', 78 =>
>   'bundle_sku_type', 79 => 'bundle_price_view', 80 =>
>   'bundle_weight_type', 81 => 'bundle_values', 82 =>
>   'bundle_shipment_type', 83 => 'configurable_variations', 84 =>
>   'configurable_variation_labels', 85 => 'associated_skus', 86 => '', 87
>   => '', )

[image]

**[UPDATE]**

For OpenOffice Below is configuration I'm using.

[image]

I have checked on Windows, Linux, Libra Office, Open Office but still no luck :(

It's not working properly, that's why i have to go long way by making custom script as below.

[Magento 2: Save all product data outside Magento with Images](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140612/magento-2-save-all-product-data-outside-magento-with-images)

**[SOLUTION]**

It's conflicting my custom Product Attribute which i named same `product_type`. Thanks to Magento Team for Pointing Out This Issue.

What i learn never used Reserverd Keywords. For more updates you can check github

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6939

Comment: you have to keep product_type as field name and set value simple or configurable in those row. Keep in mind your value doesn't contains space before or after.

Comment: just share your first row of csv for debug OR just try with only one row and check is run succesfully or not.

Comment: may be you are missing attribute_Set_code,  sku - G232 store code-Default simple

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46393/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-rakesh).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is relevant to your problem, but I had the same issue after I migrated a Magento 1.9 store.

In the Magento 1.9 store was a attribute created called Product Type. The attribute code was product_type, and the accepted values did not match simple, grouped etc.

I renamed the wrong product_type attribute in the database. After that the problem was fixed and the import run correctly.

Comment: `I renamed the wrong product_type attribute in the database.`. I'm using `Simple` Product Type Only. Can you give more details?

Answer (score 2):

The following Product File works fine for me. I use the Magento 2.1.1

> sku,name,url_key,store_view_code,attribute_set_code,product_type,color,size,categories,product_websites,description,short_description,weight,tax_class_name,visibility,price,meta_title,meta_keywords,meta_description,base_image,base_image_label,small_image,small_image_label,thumbnail_image,thumbnail_image_label,created_at,updated_at,new_from_date,new_to_date,display_product_options_in,additional_attributes,qty,out_of_stock_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,allow_backorders,use_config_backorders,min_cart_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_cart_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_on_stock_below,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,website_id,related_skus,crosssell_skus,upsell_skus,additional_images,additional_image_labels,custom_options
>   24-WG085_0,Sprite Yoga Strap 6 foot 0,sprite-yoga-strap-6-foot-0,,Default,simple,Gray,S,"Default Category/Gear,Default Category/Gear/Fitness Equipment,Default Category/Yoga/Style",base,"
>
> The Sprite Yoga Strap is your untiring partner in demanding stretches, holds and alignment routines. The straps 100% organic cotton fabric is woven tightly to form a soft, textured yet non-slip surface. The plastic clasp buckle is easily adjustable, lightweight and urable under strain.
>
> - 100% soft and durable cotton.
>
>   Plastic cinch buckle is easy to use.
>
>   Three natural colors made from phthalate and heavy metal free dyes.
>
> ","asd",1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",14,Meta Title,"meta1, meta2, meta3",meta description,model5a_2.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,01.07.2015 15:38,01.07.2015 15:38,,,Block after Info Column,"has_options=0,required_options=0,size_strap=6 foot",100,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,,,,"model3a_3.jpg,model5a_2.jpg","Image,Image","name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Gold|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Silver|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=yoga3sku,option_title=Platinum"
>   24-WG085_1,Sprite Yoga Strap 6 foot 1,sprite-yoga-strap-6-foot-1,,Default,simple,Gray,S,"Default Category/Gear,Default Category/Gear/Fitness Equipment,Default Category/Yoga/Style",base,"
>
> The Sprite Yoga Strap is your untiring partner in demanding stretches, holds and alignment routines. The straps 100% organic cotton fabric is woven tightly to form a soft, textured yet non-slip surface. The plastic clasp buckle is easily adjustable, lightweight and urable under strain.
>
> - 100% soft and durable cotton.
>
>   Plastic cinch buckle is easy to use.
>
>   Three natural colors made from phthalate and heavy metal free dyes.
>
> ","asd",1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",14,Meta Title,"meta1, meta2, meta3",meta description,model5a_2.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,01.07.2015 15:38,01.07.2015 15:38,,,Block after Info Column,"has_options=0,required_options=0,size_strap=6 foot",100,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,,,,"model3a_3.jpg,model5a_2.jpg","Image,Image","name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Gold|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Silver|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=yoga3sku,option_title=Platinum"
>   24-WG085_2,Sprite Yoga Strap 6 foot 2,sprite-yoga-strap-6-foot-2,,Default,simple,Gray,S,"Default Category/Gear,Default Category/Gear/Fitness Equipment,Default Category/Yoga/Style",base,"
>
> The Sprite Yoga Strap is your untiring partner in demanding stretches, holds and alignment routines. The straps 100% organic cotton fabric is woven tightly to form a soft, textured yet non-slip surface. The plastic clasp buckle is easily adjustable, lightweight and urable under strain.
>
> - 100% soft and durable cotton.
>
>   Plastic cinch buckle is easy to use.
>
>   Three natural colors made from phthalate and heavy metal free dyes.
>
> ","asd",1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",14,Meta Title,"meta1, meta2, meta3",meta description,model5a_2.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,01.07.2015 15:38,01.07.2015 15:38,,,Block after Info Column,"has_options=0,required_options=0,size_strap=6 foot",100,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,,,,"model3a_3.jpg,model5a_2.jpg","Image,Image","name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Gold|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Silver|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=yoga3sku,option_title=Platinum"
>   24-WG085_3,Sprite Yoga Strap 6 foot 3,sprite-yoga-strap-6-foot-3,,Default,simple,Gray,S,"Default Category/Gear,Default Category/Gear/Fitness Equipment,Default Category/Yoga/Style",base,"
>
> The Sprite Yoga Strap is your untiring partner in demanding stretches, holds and alignment routines. The straps 100% organic cotton fabric is woven tightly to form a soft, textured yet non-slip surface. The plastic clasp buckle is easily adjustable, lightweight and urable under strain.
>
> - 100% soft and durable cotton.
>
>   Plastic cinch buckle is easy to use.
>
>   Three natural colors made from phthalate and heavy metal free dyes.
>
> ","asd",1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",14,Meta Title,"meta1, meta2, meta3",meta description,model5a_2.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,01.07.2015 15:38,01.07.2015 15:38,,,Block after Info Column,"has_options=0,required_options=0,size_strap=6 foot",100,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,,,,"model3a_3.jpg,model5a_2.jpg","Image,Image","name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Gold|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Silver|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=yoga3sku,option_title=Platinum"
>   24-WG085_4,Sprite Yoga Strap 6 foot 4,sprite-yoga-strap-6-foot-4,,Default,simple,Gray,S,"Default Category/Gear,Default Category/Gear/Fitness Equipment,Default Category/Yoga/Style",base,"
>
> The Sprite Yoga Strap is your untiring partner in demanding stretches, holds and alignment routines. The straps 100% organic cotton fabric is woven tightly to form a soft, textured yet non-slip surface. The plastic clasp buckle is easily adjustable, lightweight and urable under strain.
>
> - 100% soft and durable cotton.
>
>   Plastic cinch buckle is easy to use.
>
>   Three natural colors made from phthalate and heavy metal free dyes.
>
> ","asd",1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",14,Meta Title,"meta1, meta2, meta3",meta description,model5a_2.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,01.07.2015 15:38,01.07.2015 15:38,,,Block after Info Column,"has_options=0,required_options=0,size_strap=6 foot",100,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,,,,"model3a_3.jpg,model5a_2.jpg","Image,Image","name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Gold|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Silver|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=yoga3sku,option_title=Platinum"
>   24-WG085_5,Sprite Yoga Strap 6 foot 5,sprite-yoga-strap-6-foot-5,,Default,simple,Gray,S,"Default Category/Gear,Default Category/Gear/Fitness Equipment,Default Category/Yoga/Style",base,"
>
> The Sprite Yoga Strap is your untiring partner in demanding stretches, holds and alignment routines. The straps 100% organic cotton fabric is woven tightly to form a soft, textured yet non-slip surface. The plastic clasp buckle is easily adjustable, lightweight and urable under strain.
>
> - 100% soft and durable cotton.
>
>   Plastic cinch buckle is easy to use.
>
>   Three natural colors made from phthalate and heavy metal free dyes.
>
> ","asd",1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",14,Meta Title,"meta1, meta2, meta3",meta description,model5a_2.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,01.07.2015 15:38,01.07.2015 15:38,,,Block after Info Column,"has_options=0,required_options=0,size_strap=6 foot",100,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,,,,"model3a_3.jpg,model5a_2.jpg","Image,Image","name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Gold|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Silver|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=yoga3sku,option_title=Platinum"
>   24-WG085_6,Sprite Yoga Strap 6 foot 6,sprite-yoga-strap-6-foot-6,,Default,simple,Gray,S,"Default Category/Gear,Default Category/Gear/Fitness Equipment,Default Category/Yoga/Style",base,"
>
> The Sprite Yoga Strap is your untiring partner in demanding stretches, holds and alignment routines. The straps 100% organic cotton fabric is woven tightly to form a soft, textured yet non-slip surface. The plastic clasp buckle is easily adjustable, lightweight and urable under strain.
>
> - 100% soft and durable cotton.
>
>   Plastic cinch buckle is easy to use.
>
>   Three natural colors made from phthalate and heavy metal free dyes.
>
> ","asd",1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",14,Meta Title,"meta1, meta2, meta3",meta description,model5a_2.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,01.07.2015 15:38,01.07.2015 15:38,,,Block after Info Column,"has_options=0,required_options=0,size_strap=6 foot",100,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,,,,"model3a_3.jpg,model5a_2.jpg","Image,Image","name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Gold|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Silver|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=yoga3sku,option_title=Platinum"
>   24-WG085_7,Sprite Yoga Strap 6 foot 7,sprite-yoga-strap-6-foot-7,,Default,simple,Gray,S,"Default Category/Gear,Default Category/Gear/Fitness Equipment,Default Category/Yoga/Style",base,"
>
> The Sprite Yoga Strap is your untiring partner in demanding stretches, holds and alignment routines. The straps 100% organic cotton fabric is woven tightly to form a soft, textured yet non-slip surface. The plastic clasp buckle is easily adjustable, lightweight and urable under strain.
>
> - 100% soft and durable cotton.
>
>   Plastic cinch buckle is easy to use.
>
>   Three natural colors made from phthalate and heavy metal free dyes.
>
> ","asd",1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",14,Meta Title,"meta1, meta2, meta3",meta description,model5a_2.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,01.07.2015 15:38,01.07.2015 15:38,,,Block after Info Column,"has_options=0,required_options=0,size_strap=6 foot",100,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,,,,"model3a_3.jpg,model5a_2.jpg","Image,Image","name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Gold|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Silver|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=yoga3sku,option_title=Platinum"
>   24-WG085_8,Sprite Yoga Strap 6 foot 8,sprite-yoga-strap-6-foot-8,,Default,simple,Gray,S,"Default Category/Gear,Default Category/Gear/Fitness Equipment,Default Category/Yoga/Style",base,"
>
> The Sprite Yoga Strap is your untiring partner in demanding stretches, holds and alignment routines. The straps 100% organic cotton fabric is woven tightly to form a soft, textured yet non-slip surface. The plastic clasp buckle is easily adjustable, lightweight and urable under strain.
>
> - 100% soft and durable cotton.
>
>   Plastic cinch buckle is easy to use.
>
>   Three natural colors made from phthalate and heavy metal free dyes.
>
> ","asd",1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",14,Meta Title,"meta1, meta2, meta3",meta description,model5a_2.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,01.07.2015 15:38,01.07.2015 15:38,,,Block after Info Column,"has_options=0,required_options=0,size_strap=6 foot",100,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,,,,"model3a_3.jpg,model5a_2.jpg","Image,Image","name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Gold|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Silver|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=yoga3sku,option_title=Platinum"
>   24-WG085_9,Sprite Yoga Strap 6 foot 9,sprite-yoga-strap-6-foot-9,,Default,simple,Gray,S,"Default Category/Gear,Default Category/Gear/Fitness Equipment,Default Category/Yoga/Style",base,"
>
> The Sprite Yoga Strap is your untiring partner in demanding stretches, holds and alignment routines. The straps 100% organic cotton fabric is woven tightly to form a soft, textured yet non-slip surface. The plastic clasp buckle is easily adjustable, lightweight and urable under strain.
>
> - 100% soft and durable cotton.
>
>   Plastic cinch buckle is easy to use.
>
>   Three natural colors made from phthalate and heavy metal free dyes.
>
> ","asd",1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",14,Meta Title,"meta1, meta2, meta3",meta description,model5a_2.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,model3a_3.jpg,Image Label,01.07.2015 15:38,01.07.2015 15:38,,,Block after Info Column,"has_options=0,required_options=0,size_strap=6 foot",100,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,,,,"model3a_3.jpg,model5a_2.jpg","Image,Image","name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Gold|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Silver|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=yoga3sku,option_title=Platinum"

Comment: Hi @David. Using 2.1.2. Still giving same error Hi @David. Thanks for reply. Nope still it's giving same error with your data as well `Data validation failed. Please fix the following errors and upload the file again.
Following Error(s) has been occurred during importing process:
Only the first 100 errors are shown. Download full report
1. Value for 'product_type' attribute contains incorrect value, see acceptable values on settings specified for Admin in row(s): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
2. `

Comment: How do you edit your data? May it could be a error with the file encoding? You should edit csv files with libre office and set the file encoding to utf-8

Comment: Using MS Office 2016. Please guide how to do or provide link to solve Thanks

Comment: As I already said, you should manage your csv files with libre office. It is a common problem that MS Office handles csv files in their own way. So I would recommend to handle all operations with csv files with LibreOffice or OpenOffice. https://de.libreoffice.org/

Comment: Ok Let me try @David & Check

Comment: Hi @David. No luck. I have tried with Open Office, Libre Office & Ms Office as well with `UTF-8` Encoding. Let's discuss in chat

Comment: @DavidLambauer, i have also used "LibreOffice" but till not work it getting error  as above.

Answer (score 1):

I have uploaded six simple product to magento 2.1.1 by just adding 6 new row to .csv file.

Before open .csv file check your text import and after save .csv file check the text import i am using open office 4.2.1

Below text import setting i am using and product uploaded with no error.

```
character set = unicode (UTF8)
Language = Default - English(India)
From row = 1
Separated by = Comma.
Text delimiter = "
```

I hope this will will help you!!

Comment: Tried same thing. Still giving error. Adding additional info in question.

Comment: I have uploaded this way and uploaded successfully without any error :)

Comment: Using Windows 10 64 Bit. Checked on Linux as well. Using CE 2.1.2. Don't know why it's not working on my side

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04 32 bit LTS. can you try with import export with magento sample data i hope you will find the issue if you will try this :)

Answer (score 1):

While importing only image that time also this error appear for that please check product image name. if name contain '-' then replace it with '_'.

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all import files examples for Magento 2 on our GitHub repo - https://github.com/firebearstudio/magento2-import-export-sample-files