# Magento 2: Basic Product Tables to Display on Admin & Frontend Side [SOLVED]

Tags: magento2, product, database

What are the basic tables which need to use, so Product will be shown in Admin & Frontend as well?

No need for extra attribute/image as well. Required fields & Enabled Product.

As I seen below 2 tables required. Not sure about other tables

```
catalog_product_entity
catalog_category_product
catalog_category_product_index
catalog_eav_attribute
catalog_product_website
catalog_product_entity_text
catalog_product_entity_varchar
catalog_product_entity_datetime
catalog_product_entity_decimal
catalog_product_entity_int
catalog_product_flat_1
catalog_product_index_price
cataloginventory_stock_item
cataloginventory_stock_status
cataloginventory_stock_status_idx
eav_entity_attribute
eav_attribute_option_value
url_rewrite
```

As I'm unable to import products from Backend. I'm thinking of alternatives.

Please re-confirm the above tables. This gonna be also tough. It's better someone can help with the Admin Side Product Import Issue

[Magento 2: Product Import Error - Product Type is invalid or not supported. Duplicates found in column names [SOLVED]](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139587/magento-2-product-import-error-product-type-is-invalid-or-not-supported-dupl)

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6939

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Admin side Import is not working. Have to follow this way to achieve functionality ASAP.

Managed to do below things, **But 1 issue not able to Save on Admin side. I have compared table entry with other tables as well. Please point out what I'm missing**

1. `catalog_product_entity` // Main Product Table Entry

> INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`,
> `type_id`, `sku`, `has_options`, `required_options`, `created_at`,
> `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, '16', 'simple', 'test1', '0', '0',
> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

Will Return 2049 as Product Id & will be used for Future Tables

2. `catalog_product_entity_varchar` // Title & Description & URL

> INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar` (`value_id`,
> `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '73',
> '0', '2049', 'Test 1'), (NULL, '84', '0', '2049', 'Test 1'), (NULL,
> '86', '0', '2049', 'Test 1'), (NULL, '126', '0', '2049', 'test-1');

3. `catalog_product_website` // Assign Product to Website

> INSERT INTO `catalog_product_website` (`product_id`, `website_id`)
> VALUES ('2049', '1');

4. `catalog_product_entity_decimal` // Product Price

> INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_decimal` (`value_id`,
> `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '77',
> '0', '2049', '1.11');

5. `catalog_product_index_price` // Assign All Group Wise Price

> INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price` (`entity_id`,
> `customer_group_id`, `website_id`, `tax_class_id`, `price`,
> `final_price`, `min_price`, `max_price`, `tier_price`) VALUES (2049,
> 0, 1, 2, '1.1100', '1.1100', '1.1100', '1.1100', NULL), (2049, 1, 1,
> 2, '1.1100', '1.1100', '1.1100', '1.1100', NULL), (2049, 2, 1, 2,
> '1.1100', '1.1100', '1.1100', '1.1100', NULL), (2049, 3, 1, 2,
> '1.1100', '1.1100', '1.1100', '1.1100', NULL);

6. `catalog_category_product` // Assign Product to Category

> INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product` (`entity_id`, `category_id`,
> `product_id`, `position`) VALUES (NULL, '41', '2049', '1');

7. `catalog_product_entity_int` // Enable Product & Visibility

> INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_int` (`attribute_id`, `store_id`,
> `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (133, 0, 2049, 2), (115, 0, 2049, 1),
> (99, 0, 2049, 4), (97, 0, 2049, 1);

8. `cataloginventory_stock_item` // For Inventory Quantity

> INSERT INTO `cataloginventory_stock_item` (`item_id`, `product_id`,
> `stock_id`, `qty`, `min_qty`, `use_config_min_qty`, `is_qty_decimal`,
> `backorders`, `use_config_backorders`, `min_sale_qty`,
> `use_config_min_sale_qty`, `max_sale_qty`, `use_config_max_sale_qty`,
> `is_in_stock`, `low_stock_date`, `notify_stock_qty`,
> `use_config_notify_stock_qty`, `manage_stock`,
> `use_config_manage_stock`, `stock_status_changed_auto`,
> `use_config_qty_increments`, `qty_increments`,
> `use_config_enable_qty_inc`, `enable_qty_increments`,
> `is_decimal_divided`, `website_id`) VALUES (2049, 2049, 1, '100.0000',
> '0.0000', 1, 0, 0, 1, '1.0000', 1, '10000.0000', 1, 1, NULL, '1.0000',
> 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, '1.0000', 1, 0, 0, 0);

9. `url_rewrite` // For URL Rewrite

> INSERT INTO `url_rewrite` (`entity_type`, `entity_id`, `request_path`,
> `target_path`, `redirect_type`, `store_id`, `description`,
> `is_autogenerated`, `metadata`) VALUES ('product', 2049,
> 'coins/test-1.html', 'catalog/product/view/id/2049/category/41', 0, 1,
> NULL, 1, 'a:1:{s:11:"category_id";s:2:"41";}'), ('product', 2049,
> 'test-1.html', 'catalog/product/view/id/2049', 0, 1, NULL, 1, NULL);

Check the `eav_attribute` table which stores ALL Attributes

10] `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category` // For URL Rewrite

> INSERT INTO `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category` (`url_rewrite_id`,
> `category_id`, `product_id`) VALUES ('631', '41', '2049');

After this, you are able to see your Product on the Frontend

Execute Below Command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

You can see your newly created product entry in Below tables now

```
catalog_category_product_index
catalog_product_flat_1
cataloginventory_stock_status
cataloginventory_stock_status_idx
```

Issue: When i go to `Admin -> Catalog -> Edit` Product & Save. It's not doing anything. Just Hold Over there. No Errors displayed on Admin or in Console no issue logged in Log file as well.

**[UPDATE - Solution]**

I'm using my new "Attribute Set" in that some of the Attributes are Mandatory fields.

I have added that attribute entry in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` & it's work fine now :)