# Add all products to websites/storeview by sql

Tags: magento2, products, sql, assign

I have more then 10k products in base store and want now assign all to new website as multistore in system with/by sql how i assign all products to the new websites/storeviews using sql?

use Magento 2.3.3

I have the WebSite ID´s: 4, 5, 6 where i want assign all products in bulk by sql query in one step

Comment: refer this link :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140097/magento-2-basic-product-tables-to-display-on-admin-frontend-side-solved 2> backup the this table and import the new websites

Comment: thanks for fast feedback if i use this string:
INSERT INTO catalog_product_website (product_id, website_id) VALUES ('2049', '1'); i must define every product by id but i want it for all in the query

Comment: Stefan, then create a script to select all products and create the required SQL based off the example?

Comment: @StefanStrasser , can you please give me sql query to assign all products to new website, I have around 3 laks product. can you please give me sql query