# Magento 2: Product/Customer Attribute with Dropdown Not Taking it's Given Value

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, custom

I'm creating product attribute Color with Dropdown. Red, Blue, Green, etc. from Admin.

When i try to set it's value programatically, then i can't use "Red", "Blue", "Green"

It will store paticular ID for that 10,11,12. So i need to use that.

How can i set from Admin, so it only uses it Value, Not Number.

**Example:**

If i have Lable has options A, B, C.

So in database it stores as Id. So for A -> 10, B -> 20, C-> 30.

When we going to save this by custom we need to use 10 which in annoying. How to use A for this?

Comment: What you exactly want to do?
set it from admin or programatically?

Comment: Would like to save value if "Red" is Option then "Red" is value. Not Number or ID of DB Field