# Magento 2: Import Script Store Id Related Issue

Tags: magento2, product, import, custom

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.3

[Magento 2: Save all product data outside Magento with Images](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140612/magento-2-save-all-product-data-outside-magento-with-images)

Once I imported data from CSV using above script.

If put as `->setStoreId(0)`, then it will add two values for same Field In Database Table. One as `Store Id` `0` & Second As `Store Id` `1`.

Example: `catalog_product_entity_varchar`

```
value_id    attribute_id store_id entity_id     value
100           70           0       10           Test
101           70           1       10           Test <- NOT NEEDED ENTRY
```

`attribute_id` `70` is for `name (Product Name)` from Table `eav_attribute`

Due to 2 values for Same Field. Each time have to delete Store Id 1 related value from Database respective Table, then it works fine on Frontend.

At the end data is not displaying properly as needed. Have to do each time Delete Query for Store Id in 5-6 tables.

Go to **Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> General -> General -> Single Store Mode**

It always been issue. On Admin side it's taking Store Id 0 value & on frontend displays it's taking Store Id 1 Value.

> Enable Single-Store Mode set to "Yes"

```
On Admin -> All Store Views -> Store Id = 0 -> Admin Using This
On Admin -> Default Store Views -> Store Id = 1 -> Frontend Using This
```

What i'm still missing in Script? Does **Enable Single-Store Mode set to "Yes"** helps?

Other workaround will be set Admin to Default Store Views. In my case i have only 1 store. So may be works.

While we do Default Magento Import/Export. It only uses **Store Id 0**  & it works fine.

Comment: You can try with $state->setAreaCode('adminhtml') in your script;

Comment: It will solve Frontend  & Backend Both issues? No need to setStoreId ?

Comment: I havent try with that but try with that so may be generate one entry in table

Comment: Hi @Rakesh have tried. Not working :( I have removed `setStoreId` & setAreaCode as adminhtml. After Import, if anything i changes on Admin it's not refelcting on Frontend.

Comment: Hi @AnkitShah I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: As per ur admin settings It should be always 0 or 1. Not both at the time. Then it will proritize 0 or 1 value. Last u have to move 1 value 0 & clear out DB every time once u import

Answer (score 3):

```
$objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->setCurrentStore('admin');
```

before importing the products will have the products use store id 0 ('admin') only

Looking at `module-catalog\Model\ProductRepository.php:save()` **(Magento 2.1.2)**  it seems that the store id is retrieved from the current store on save, and not the one set via `Product::setStoreId():`

```
$productDataArray['store_id'] = (int)$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
```

Comment: So what is solution?

Comment: Set the current store to 'admin' once before saving your products in the import process:

    $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->setCurrentStore('admin');

Comment: It's giving fatal error  `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterfa‌​ce does not exist'`

Comment: You save my day. Just saying you should NEVER use object manager but use it as a dependency. this worked for me :         $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore(0);
                            $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($store);

Answer (score 1):

Here's one thing to try. Generally in Magento, at least in v1 (and I think the pattern would carry over to v2), the right way to change the area of the store is through emulation. In Magento 2, we use the `Magento\Framework\App\State::emulateAreaCode()` method for this.

Try using that to run your script, and let me know how it works. Use it like this: `$state->emulateAreaCode('frontend', $callable)`, where `$callable` is the code you want to run. For this approach, you will have to move your import code into a separate function.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Hi @tjons. As u seen in question. I have put the link in beginning. use `Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');` What should be value of `$callable`?

Comment: Move your script import process into a separate function in the same file. Then pass the name to it as a string, e.g., `emulateAreaCode('frontend', 'yourfuncname');`. Let me know if that works...

Comment: Ok got it @tjons. Let me check & revert back to you. Thanks. Does it affect `Enable Single-Store Mode set to "Yes"`?

Comment: Nope. Still issue remains same :(

Comment: @AnkitShah can you add your script to the question? Not a link, but the actual code you're trying to run...

Comment: Already provided here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140612/magento-2-save-all-product-data-outside-magento-with-images

Comment: Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: @AnkitShah try replacing the value `frontend` in  `emulateAreaCode('frontend', $callable)` with `adminhtml`.

Comment: Let me know if that works...

Comment: That i already tried. Not Working

Answer (score 0):

Try this before saving product from custom script csv import

$_product->setData('store_id', 0);

$_product->save();

This should be only one record storeId 0  in your database

I have tested and fixed same above issue due to custom csv import module

Answer (score 0):

Known issue for some time, a fix is in the way it seems?
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8897