# Magento 2: Admin Set to "Default Store View"

Tags: magento2, admin, catalog, store-view

[Magento 2: Import Script Store Id Related Issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147042/magento-2-import-script-store-id-related-issue)

Would like to set Admin to "Default Store View" instead of "All Store Views".

How to do it? Is it good idea to achieve my requirement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2: Import Script Store Id Related Issue](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147042/magento-2-import-script-store-id-related-issue)