# Magento 2 Product images not display for another store after upload products using programatically

Tags: magento2, product-images, image-upload

I have upload some products using script. I am using below code for upload images.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$product_images = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
 ->load($product->getId());

$product_images->addImageToMediaGallery($img, 
        array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);

$product_images->save();
```

I have 2 stores and after upload product data i can see products images on first store and on second store i can only see product images on product detail page.

i can't see products images on home page and product list page for second store.

i have already doing indexing and caching process.

can you please help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to ***Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> General -> General -> Single-Store Mode***

> Enable Single-Store Mode to **Yes**

& `setStoreId(1);`

[Magento 2: Save all product data outside Magento with Images](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140612/magento-2-save-all-product-data-outside-magento-with-images)

Follow above URL