# how to import product images programmatically in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-images, magento-2.0.7

How to import product images programmatically using csv.

In my csv I mentioned the product sku,base,small images names.

Overall there are 4000 products are there.

Please help me out of this.

I done through admin as explained in http://docs.magento.com But still no luck.

Comment: Welcome to Magento Stack Exchange. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140612/magento-2-save-all-product-data-outside-magento-with-images

Comment: @AnkitShah Thanks... But where I need to place this code.

Comment: Please create file on your magento root folder where  you have app & other folders

Comment: @AnkitShah Thanks... Its working well bro.. But I am having a csv file which contains all details related to product images, sku and price etc. How to fetch the data from it.

Comment: Just put one column in CSV file for each. Image 1 1 Column, Image 2 Second Column. For each one Make one Sepearate Column & Fetch

Comment: @AnkitShah sorry still no luck...