# Magento 2: How to Insert Multiple Records to custom table?

Tags: magento2, model, save

I have created a new table in Magento2: `my_custom_table` with 4 fields:

```
id: primary key, 
product_id: int(11), 
customer_id: int(11)
status:int(11)
```

I  want to save multiple records at a time. Here is my code.

```
namespace Company\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;    

class Save extends \Company\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index
    {

        protected $_filterProvider;
        protected $productModel;


        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
            \Company\Module\Model\Product  $productModel

        ) {
            $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
            $this->productModel = $productModel;      

            parent::__construct($context,$registry);
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            if ($data) {
                $products = array(12,13,14,14);
                $customerId = 1;
                foreach($products as $pdt){
                    $productModel = $this->productModel;                                  
                    $productModel->setData('product_id',$pdt);
                    $productModel->setData('customer_id',$customerId);
                    $productModel->setData('product_status',1);
                    $productModel->save();
                }
            }
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/new');
        }

    }
```

Please help me

Comment: As far as i know only u can do with for loop.

Comment: But it adds only one row

Comment: Follow this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140612/magento-2-save-all-product-data-outside-magento-with-images

Comment: Please share your modules, complete code, also make sure your primary key should be auto increment.

Comment: yes. primary key is auto increment. Please check the updated code

Comment: There is no other way to do that? I think this way is not the proper way, calling save method multiple times doesn't seems good to performance ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We forgot to **unset data model** after saving.

```
$productModel->save();
$productModel->unsetData();
```

**[EDIT]**

Using model Factory can solve our issue. For example, inject `Company\Module\Model\ProductFactory` in constructor . Inside the loop, we just need to create the factory.

```
$product = $this->productFactory->create();
$product->setData(....);
$product->save();
```