# Magento 2 Product import error :. Value for 'product_type' attribute contains incorrect value

Tags: magento-2.1, import, product-import

I'm using Magento 2 Version 2.1 .
I have migrated data from magento 1.9 to magento 2.1.

The csv looks like, this:

sku,product_type,additional_attributes
123,simple,brands=APPLE,hideprice_by_customergroup=General|Wholesale|Retailer,hide_price=1,product_type=Enclosures,url_path=10invsp.html

I have exported CSV File. it's not working. it showing error.
[image]

Comment: Check product type column check memory limit

Comment: where I can check the memory limit?

Comment: Do you have any solution for this error?

Comment: you are facing same issue which magento version you have?

Comment: I am using Magento 2.1.14 and I want to update price but I received Product_type error.

Comment: have you added product_type in your csv  if all product are simple then add a column with `product_type` and add value `simple`

Comment: I did but it showing me same error

Comment: check it https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139587/magento-2-product-import-error-product-type-is-invalid-or-not-supported-dupl

Comment: I tried this link but no results

Comment: do you know : I renamed the wrong product_type attribute in the database. After that the problem was fixed and the import run correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need make sure need at least attributes below for your csv import file

> sku,product_type,attribute_set_code,categories,name,description,price,qty